# Хэлп! Пропали системные настройки

Tags: cms, modx

В админке пропали системные настройки: ibb.co/CMbDP5y
Не отображается ни под какими пользователями, даже под записью администратора с полными правами. Галочка на «settings» в настройках политики доступа для Administrator стоит. При открытии страницы настроек никаких сообщений об ошибках в лог не сыплется.
Что было опробовано: чистил кеш, открывал в другом браузере, обновлял modx.
Откатить к последнему бэкапу не вариант, после его создания было внесено очень много правок. Не хочется заново всё это ручками набирать. 
Может кто сталкивался, подскажите, плз!

Answer (score 0):

А после чего пропали-то? Какие действия совершали, что к этому результату пришли?

- Как вариант(помогало не раз в случае с пустой админкой) - отключите
  экстра, можно часть или все(особенно косячны Ace, TinyMCE и т.п)
- Права самые максимальные выставлены админу?
- А сообщений в консоли браузера тоже нет?
- И в папке Сеть в консоли разработчика все коннекты проходят успешно?